# Why does my robotium test case does not start immediately after launching the activity?

Tags: android, robotium, instrumentation

I have build a Robotium test case for my application. Everything works good except from the fact that i need to manually interact with my app to get the test start running. Meaning i need to go to another activity in the app and then the test case will start.
For some reason my test does not start on start up.

```
public class TestApk extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2{
private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID= "com.bizzabo.client";
private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME="com.bizzabo.client.ui.activities.BzLauncher";
private static Class launcherActivityClass;
static{
    try
    {
        launcherActivityClass=Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }}
public TestApk()throws ClassNotFoundException{
    super( launcherActivityClass);
}
private Solo solo;
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());

}

public void testInformationMenu() {
    final int INFORMATION_VIEW_NO = 11;

    solo.getCurrentActivity();
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.goBack();
    solo.sleep(1000);
    ArrayList<View> viewList = solo.getCurrentViews();
    solo.clickOnView(viewList.get(INFORMATION_VIEW_NO));
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.clickOnText("Add Event");
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.goBack();
    solo.clickOnView(viewList.get(INFORMATION_VIEW_NO));
    solo.clickOnText("Invite Your Friends");
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.goBack();
    solo.clickOnView(viewList.get(10));
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.enterText(0, "testbot");
    solo.sendKey(Solo.ENTER);
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnImage(2);
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.clickOnText("Join");
    solo.goBack();
    solo.clickOnText("Community");
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.clickOnText("Join");
    solo.goBack();
    solo.clickOnText("HERE NOW");
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.clickOnText("Check-In");
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.goBack();
    solo.clickOnText("Opportunities");
    solo.clickOnText("Messages");
    solo.clickOnText("Offers");
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.clickOnText("Event");
    solo.goBack();
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.clickOnText("Information");
    solo.clickOnText("Join");
    solo.goBack();
    solo.clickOnText("+ Invite");
    solo.goBack();
    solo.clickOnText("Buzz");
    solo.goBack();
    solo.goBack();
    solo.drag(400, 400, 400, 300, 1);
    solo.sleep(1000);
}

public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be as simple as calling your superclasses:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());
}
```

and

```
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}
```

This should help set up everything and your tests will run properly, assuming that your classname is right of course!

Answer (score 0):

On this line you write activity from which test will start:

```
LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME="com.bizzabo.client.ui.activities.BzLauncher";
```

Check properly activity you need to start for.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in my application. On my Activity i have a custom view(webview) which displays gif-animation.  If i remove this view from Activity, test starts on a start up. But if that view exists, test do not proceed until i manually switch to next Activity.